In CommonLisp, Is it possible to make compiled codes remember compile time information and reference it later at runtime
A legitimate use case is to remember the time when the program was built. With following codes saved in file "foo.lisp":
(in-package :cl-user)

(defvar *compilation-time* nil)

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel)
  (setf *compilation-time* (multiple-value-bind (s m h)
                               (decode-universal-time (get-universal-time))
                             (format nil "~D:~D:~D" h m s))))

(format t "Built at: ~A~%" *compilation-time*)

(defvar *compilation-path* nil)

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel)
  (setf *compilation-path* *compile-file-pathname*))

(format t "Built from: ~A" *compilation-path*)


In a new sbcl session:
# sbcl --noinform --no-userinit
* (compile-file "foo")
; compiling file "/tmp/common-lisp/foo.lisp" (written 18 APR 2024 05:21:25 PM):

; wrote /tmp/common-lisp/foo.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.006
#P"/tmp/common-lisp/foo.fasl"
NIL
NIL
* *compilation-time*
"17:33:20"

My understanding is that :compile-toplevel forms evaluated because I compiled the file. So in that sbcl session, *compilation-time* was set. However, if start a new session, and load the already compiled fasl file, *compilation-time* is empty!
# sbcl --noinform --no-userinit
* (load "foo.fasl")
Built at: NIL
Built from: NIL
T
*

Obviously, the "foo.fasl" file does not remember when it was built.
My question: Is it possible to make the fasl file actually remember the compile time information, and reference those information in future sessions?

Sure, how should it work? Your code does not set the variable at load time.
Maybe something like this (untested):
(defmacro updating-compilation-time ()
   `(setf *compilation-time*
          ,(multiple-value-bind (s m h)
               (decode-universal-time (get-universal-time))
             (format nil "~D:~D:~D" h m s))))

(updating-compilation-time)

or
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel)
  (setf *compilation-time*
        (multiple-value-bind (s m h)
             (decode-universal-time (get-universal-time))
           (format nil "~D:~D:~D" h m s))))

(defmacro updating-compilation-time ()
   `(setf *compilation-time*
          ,*compilation-time*))

(updating-compilation-time)


Rainer Joswig already answered the direct question.
However, in this case might be simpler to use #. macro. Caveat: It captures not compile time but read time value - but it should still be adequate for the stated purpose (to keep when the app was built).
(setf *compilation-time* #.(multiple-value-bind (s m h)
                               (decode-universal-time (get-universal-time))
                             (format nil "~2,'0D:~2,'0D:~2,'0D" h m s)))

